# Update FROM query JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi I need to do an UPDATE with the following JPQL.

```
UPDATE AreaCoberturaSedes a SET a.seleccionado = acs.seleccionado
FROM AreaCoberturaSedes acs JOIN acs.sedesNegociacion sn 
WHERE acs.municipio.id = a.municipio.id 
AND sn.negociacion.id = :negociacionId AND sn.id = :sedeNegociacionId
```

The native query will be

```
UPDATE contratacion.area_cobertura_sedes a  SET seleccionado = acs.seleccionado
 FROM contratacion.area_cobertura_sedes acs INNER JOIN contratacion.sedes_negociacion sn ON sn.id = acs.sede_negociacion_id
 WHERE acs.municipio_id = a.municipio_id
 AND sn.negociacion_id = 34 AND sn.id = 67
```

and works fine.

But with JPA throws the following exception:

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (default task-47) line 1:123: unexpected token: FROM: line 1:123: unexpected token: FROM
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.updateStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:261) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:169) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:443) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
```

Comment: `UPDATE ... FROM..`  is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refresh your knowledge of a JPQL UPDATE query from this link. There is no FROM.

> ```
> UPDATE [<candidate-class>] SET item1=value1, item2=value2
>     [WHERE <filter>]
> ```

See [this post](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/jpql.html#JPQL_UPDATE_Queries) for more information.